# Unable to delete TF Workspace

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

Why am I unable to delete this? I have tried every possible method but I cannot delete or create a new workspace for the user.

I accidentally delete the user in Active Directory then I recreated the user again with the same username, and recreated his profile on the machine, since then I am unable to create the workspace, I tried deleting it from TFS / VS first didn't work, I also deleted the folder U_C which is the local root directory for TFS data

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to delete the workspace with the user's unique id instead of its name.

Firstly, you need to run the command below:

```
tf workspaces /computer:* /owner:* /format:xml
```

And then you'll find a string that represents the user, in the form of GUID with email.

Then replace the user's name in delete command with that string

```
tf workspace /delete {workspace};{string}
```

**Update:**

An example:

```
tf workspace /delete WorkSpace1;72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db44\xxxx@outlook.com
```

Comment: @Aasim Shakil Pathan Sorry for the late reply. I tried this method on my side and it worked well. I have updated my answer to give an example, you can check your command with it. If possible, could you provide more details about your test failure so that people can better investigate the question?

Comment: Thank You so much, I had to do this from another computer and modify your command to set /computer:* to /computer:COMPUTERNAMEWITHTHEISSUE but once I got the results I was able to delete the duplicate Workspace with the same name. Happy New Year!